Degrees of Freedom in a phylogenetic ANOVA
Does anyone know how to find the degrees of freedom using a phylogenetic anova? Specifically, I am using phylANOVA from phytools. Is it the same way to calculate other degrees of freedom, or does it change since it is taking phylogeny into account?
I have tried looking for d.f. in any residual results, but can't seem to find it.
